# Jest, React testing a component not exist

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this test:

```
const rendered = render(
  <TransactionReason
    reason={{ code: defaultReason }}
  />
);

expect(rendered.getByTestId('reasonInput')).toBeNull();
```

What I'm trying to do is: there is a component that has the `testID = 'reasonInput'`, but this component is not rendered when the `reason` prop has that value that I'm giving (code: defaultReason). But I get an error because Jest can't find that id, of course, is not rendered. I thought that that would produce a false or null value, that's why I tried with `toBeNull` or `toBeFalsy` or something like that.

How could I then test the not existance of that component?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [the reference](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#variants) states, the difference between `getByTestId` and `queryByTestId` is that the former throws an error if there is no matching element:

> getBy* queries return the first matching node for a query, and throw
> an error if no elements match or if more than one match is found (use
> getAllBy instead).
>
> queryBy* queries return the first matching node for a query, and
> return null if no elements match. This is useful for asserting an
> element that is not present. This throws if more than one match is
> found (use queryAllBy instead).

It should be:

```
expect(rendered.queryByTestId('reasonInput')).toBeNull();
```